# Flex 3: How can i simulate the enter/return key being pressed

Tags: apache-flex, keyboard-events

Title pretty much says it all... is there an easy way I can simulate the enter/return key being pressed?

EDIT:

I've got this much, but i'm not sure how to make it run in a loop:

```
var keyCode:uint = Keyboard.ENTER;
var e:KeyboardEvent = new KeyboardEvent(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, true, false, 0, keyCode);
```

I need it to run in the following loop:

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < changes.length; i++)
{
    if (changes[i][0] == "directorsPrep")
    {
        directorsPrep[changes[i][1]].phaseFillers[changes[i][2]].fillDisplayName.setFocus();
        // NEED IT TO RUN RIGHT HERE!
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried dispatching a keyboard event on the stage, or simply calling whatever your keyboard handler is with a constructed keyboard event?

Comment: @AmyBlankenship - I tried googling for this, but I couldn't find anything that lead me to the correct answer.  I've tried tweaking what I was able to find, but nothing worked.

Comment: And "what you were able to find" is what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < changes.length; i++)
{
    if (changes[i][0] == "directorsPrep")
    {
        directorsPrep[changes[i][1]].phaseFillers[changes[i][2]].fillDisplayName.setFocus();
        // NEED IT TO RUN RIGHT HERE!
        // create the keyboard event; using your code
        var keyCode:uint = Keyboard.ENTER;
        var e:KeyboardEvent = new KeyboardEvent(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, true, false, 0, keyCode);
        // dispatch it    
        componentThatYouWantToDispatchKeyBoardEvent.dispatchEvent(e);
    }
}
```

The `componentThatYouWantToDispatchKeyBoardEvent` variable can be any component that extends [EventDispatcher](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/EventDispatcher.html) or implements [IEventDispatcher](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/IEventDispatcher.html).

Comment: Thanks, that worked... but it didn't fix the issue i'm having :(.  Good to know anyways though :)